# Emacs auto-complete: don't trigger on RET in inline suggestion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I am very happy with auto-complete but one thing bugs me:

I'm setup to show the inline suggestion immediately but the menu with 0.9 s delay. I type the first few letters e.g. "del" which get immediately auto-completed inline to "delete". If I wanted to type "delete" I hit `TAB` and this is alright. But what if I wanted to actually type "del" and a newline - here hitting `RET` again auto-completes to "delete".

How can I force `RET` to be newline if only inline suggestion is shown? Once the auto-complete menu is displayed I want it to be the trigger key again as usual.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `del Ctrl-d`. I'm not at a computer I can check this with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding the following lines after other settings for the `auto-complete` mode, you can enable completion by <kbd>RET</kbd> only when completion menu is displayed:

```lisp
(define-key ac-completing-map "\C-m" nil)
(setq ac-use-menu-map t)
(define-key ac-menu-map "\C-m" 'ac-complete)
```

`ac-completing-map` is a keymap where <kbd>RET</kbd> is by default bound to `ac-complete`, and `ac-menu-map` is a keymap for completion on completion menu. The `ac-menu-map` keymap is enabled when the `ac-use-menu-map` variable is `t`.

FYI, completion can be stopped by pressing <kbd>C-g</kbd> at any time. So you will also be able to hit <kbd>C-g</kbd> and <kbd>RET</kbd> to enter a newline with the bindings of <kbd>RET</kbd> intact. Also, you can use <kbd>C-j</kbd> rather than <kbd>RET</kbd> when you want to enter a newline. <kbd>C-j</kbd> does not bind to `ac-complete` by default.

Comment: Thank you! This works! I knew about C-g (I also have ESC bound to this functionality), but that breaks the smooth flow.