# ESS mode: unbind autocomplete from "return" key

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, ess

In Emacs ESS mode, is there a way to **unbind auto-completion/auto-substitution** from `<return>` key and leave only `<tab>` (or some other key) for this purpose?

---

I'm using this mode to edit Julia code (not R, but there should be little difference) and in most cases it works great. However, there several use cases when auto-completion on `<return>` key makes experience just terrible. Here are my favourite two:

- when I write a function and press `<return>` just after keyword `end` to get to the next line, auto-complete replaces `end` first available substitution - `endof`
- if I have variable `mat`, type it into REPL and press `<return>` to print it out, auto-completion substitutes variable `mat` with type `Matrix`

Is there a way to unbind this behavior from `<return>` key?

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12661187/2112489  A quick grep of the source code for ess-mode led me to think that perhaps your issue is not an ess-mode setting, but rather has more to do with auto-complete.

Comment: @lawlist: thanks, it seems to be the best option available at the moment. Could you please post it as an answer (including note that it is about auto-complete mode and not ESS mode - it was essential for me)?